# Using Dockerfile ARG within an ADD statement

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to create a dockerfile that adds files from build directory to the working directory.

The build directory can vary and thus needs to be specified by an argument:

```
ARG BUILD_SOURCE

FROM node:8.11.4

WORKDIR /usr/local/app

ADD "$BUILD_SOURCE" .
```

I ran this with `docker build BUILD_SOURCE=bin/bundle .`.

Somehow the ARG is not substituted so that the whole current directory is added to the image.

When I hardcode the build source it works fine.

I have tried using `ENV` instead, copying the arg into the the env like this:

```
ENV BUILD_SOURCE $BUILD_SOURCE
ADD "${BUILD_SOURCE}" .
```

That didn't work either.

In the official docker documentation I cannot find this behaviour being mentioned.

Does anybody why this is happening and what possible workaround would be?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out.

The `ARG` must be placed below the `FROM` statement unless it is used within the `FROM` statement:

```
FROM node:8.11.4

ARG BUILD_SOURCE

WORKDIR /usr/local/app

ADD "$BUILD_SOURCE" .
```